# OpenCart resources

Tags: php, resources, reference, webshop, opencart

I'm trying to develop an understanding of how to build things using OpenCart, but their documentation seem to bit on the conservative side. Do the stackoverflow community have suggestions for reading material.

This question is in spirit related to:

- [Resources on wordpress theme-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708/resources-on-wordpress-theme-development)
- [Good resources for Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817063/good-resources-for-wordpress)

Comment: This will help getting started with developing a theme:
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-an-opencart-3-theme/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could buy their beginner's guide [Opencart Beginner's guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513023)

Comment: I don't see how this as an answer - anyone can recommend a book, what happened to taking the time to gather tutorials, resources, in-depth analysis and links to existing SO questions threads and / or suggesting a OpenCart codex and wiki? -Downvote.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid He was asking for a reading material and I shared one I had used, could you please share some resources that has done some in-depth analysis on the same so that we can all read it ?

Comment: For the experienced developer, this site has proven very useful to me: http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=development

Answer (score 8):

First you need to get familiar with the concept of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Then take a look at [OpenCart framework](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=4113) explanation to have a better understanding of MVC implementation in OpenCart.

The rest shouldn't be that hard, just go through some examples and you'll get the idea. [This example](http://opencart.hostjars.com/writing-modules) is really good to get you started. It's written for training purpose and all files are well commented ! In order to download the example you need to submit an order and then download the attachment from the "Downloads" section. You can also find more tutorials at this [link](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=17933) ...

Comment: This should've been the selected answer. Great help thanks @Tohid

Answer (score 5):

If its only about changing the theme of OpenCart, then for this, working experience with any template engine like Smarty can prove to be beneficial.

But if its about extending and modifying the functionality, then knowledge of MVC as a whole would definitely be more beneficial.

If you don't want to invest time in first understanding MVC, then simply dive into the code straight away and try understanding how files are being loaded  (die(), exit() the best means for this).

Note that be it MVC or any other pattern, open-cart or any other tool/solution, the most rewarding way of having a good hold on it is to focus upon understanding the bootstrap process or file loading mechanism and this can be best achieved by going through code logically and understanding its flow (again by using die or exit).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by learning the MVC development framework.  If you understand how an MVC framework is built, then you're already on your way to understanding Opencart.  Codeigniter is a fairly simple MVC framework to learn off of and there is lots of resources around to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I've been wrote something about "[good resource for Opencart](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=21479)" on Opencart forum. See developing refference section.

Answer (score 0):

For changing or adding functionality, you should consider using [vqmod](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/), it allows you to change things without modifying the opencart source code directly, which is ideal if you do upgrades or want to port your changes to other opencart installs.

It is also nice to share them with the community if they are particularly helpful.